# Verification of matrix chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I wrote down a simple example of function composition for multivariate and vector-valued functions to see if I can apply the matrix chain rule. I would appreciate it if someone could verify that this is a correct application of the matrix chain rule.

Unfortunately, all the examples I can find online are either partial derivatives (not the total derivative matrix) or functions that are scalar valued, which is not what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried verifying your result by computing $f\circ g$ explicitly and differentiating that directly? You’ll end up with something quite different than the above because you’re confusing coordinates of the domain of $g$ with those of $f$.

Comment: You have $Dh(x)=Df(g(x))\circ Dg(x)$. The issue is that you used $Df(x)$ instead of $Df(g(x))$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you @IvoTerek. I'm posting an answer, I'll give people some time to review it if any do and I'll accept it.

Comment: Instead of posting pictures of your work, please take the time to enter it as text. Your question should be comprehensible without the images. They are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rules says that $D(f\circ g)(\mathbf x) = Df(g(\mathbf x))\circ Dg(\mathbf x)$. Expanded in terms of coordinates, the right-hand side becomes the product of the Jacobian matrices of $f$ and $g$ evaluated at the appropriate points. You computed the Jacobians and multiplied them, but you evaluated $Df$ at the point $\mathbf x$ instead of at $g(\mathbf x)$. I recommend renaming the variables in the definition of $f$ to help prevent this.

So, using $y_k$ instead of $x_k$ in the definition of $f$, we have $$Df = \begin{bmatrix}1&y_3&y_2\\2y_1&0&0\\y_2&y_1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \\ Dg = \begin{bmatrix}x_2&x_1\\2x_1x_2&x_1^2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ and so $$Df(g(\mathbf x))Dg(\mathbf x) = \begin{bmatrix}1&x_2&x_1^2x_2\\2x_1x_2&0&0\\x_1^2x_2&x_1x_2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_2&x_1\\2x_1x_2&x_1^2\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_2+2x_1x_2^2&x_1+2x_1^2x_2\\2x_1x_2^2&2x_1^2x_2\\3x_1^2x_2^2&2x_1^3x_2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The two individual matrices agree with your updated answer, but it looks like you omitted the last row of the product.

To check this, we compute $D(f\circ g)(\mathbf x)$ directly. We have $$f\circ g: (x_1,x_2)\mapsto \left(x_1^2x_2^2+x_1x_2,x_1^2x_2^2,x_1^3x_2^2,x_2\right),$$ so $$D(f\circ g)(\mathbf x) = \begin{bmatrix}2x_1x_2^2+x_2&2x_1^2x_2+x_1\\2x_1x_2^2&2x_1^2x_2\\3x_1^2x_2^2&2x_1^3x_2\\0&1\end{bmatrix},$$ which agrees with the other calculation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As IvoTerek's comment mentions, I calculated df/dx and multiplied that by dg/dx, instead I should've calculated df/dg. This is an updated answer, first I calculate the composition f(g(x)), and then take the total derivative with respect to g(x), and then multiply that by the total derivative of g(x) wrt x.

EDIT:

Edited after comment by @amd. First calculate df/dx and evaluate it at g, which I denote by df(g)/dg. And then multiply by dg/dx. I have verified this answer against the straightforward calculation of df(g(x))/dx.

Comment: Still wrong. You need to _evaluate_ $Df$ at $g(\mathbf x)$ and multiply that by the value of $Dg$ at $\mathbf x$. I suggest using different names for the variables in the definition of $f$ to keep things straight. Since you’ve already worked out an explicit expression for $f\circ g$ (which, incidentally, doesn’t look quite right to me), try differentiating that directly to see what your result should be, as I suggested in my earlier comment to your question.

Comment: @amd Thanks! I made the change and verified it against the derivative of the composition. Now it seems correct.

Comment: Does it? $f(g(x_1,x_2))=(\dots,x_2)$, so the last row ought to be $(0,1)$. That’s certainly what I get when I multiply the two matrices in your updated answer.

Comment: @amd ahh, I forgot the last row. Thx for your detailed answer below, I'll accept it.